# Particles in the Passive form causing me confusion (を、に、が)

Tags: usage

Sometimes, I dont know what particles to use in the passive form に、を、が。

ワインを飲まれた

ワインに飲まれた

ワインが飲まれた

I REALLY dont understand the difference between those three. Is the first one that uses を　indicating that there is a subject that drank the wine? Do all of them mean that the wine has been drunk?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We usually do not say 'ワインに飲まれた'. It would mean 'Something was drunk by wine'. 
'ワインを飲まれた' sounds to me like 'Someone drank "my" wine'.
I think 'ワインが飲まれた' just means '(The) wine was drunk./Someone or some people drank (the) wine.' In this sentence the wine might not have been mine.

Comment: @user1087 Perhaps it is worth adding that the reason the を version sounds like "My" wine has been drunk by someone, is because it is in this case what seems to be commonly called the "suffering passive" (I don't know if that is the proper term for it; I'm not a linguist...), because it can describe how the receiver of the action could suffer in some way, meaning there must be some receiver of the action, as opposed to the に version (I think). For example you could say 財布を盗まれた instead of 財布が盗まれた. Perhaps someone else can explain better but I thought I would give it a shot.

Comment: @SourLemon. Another term for "suffering passive" that I think that is commonly used is "adversity passive".

Comment: Nitpicking: Considering the saying 酒は飲んでも飲まれるな, one might say ワインに飲まれる to mean “to lose oneself in wine.”  (But I am not suggesting to add this to your answer, because this usage is kind of exceptional.)